# my PowerShell script task successful in azure devops pipeline but set variable is not created

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to create a dynamic variable on Azure Devops pipeline and I cannot use it on further tasks although the task with the variable creation is successfully completed.

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=mytitle;isOutput=true]$content
```

How can I use the variable that is created dynamically with `setvariable`

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the **first** task can set a variable, and **following** tasks are able to use the variable using macro syntax `$(myVar)`. We are not able to use it in the first task. The variable will only be available to tasks in the same job by default, and the variable is exposed to the following tasks as an environment variable.

For example:

```
jobs:
- job: A
  steps:
  - powershell: |
     Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=mytitle]$content"
    name: setVariable
  - powershell: |
     Write-Host "You can use macro syntax for variables: $(mytitle)"
    name: PrintVariable
```

If you add the parameter `isoutput`, the syntax to call your variable changes.  See [Set an output variable for use in the same job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#set-an-output-variable-for-use-in-the-same-job) and [Set an output variable for use in future jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#set-an-output-variable-for-use-in-future-jobs) for details.

More information please refer to [Logging commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable).

Comment: hi it is not at all creating the variable itself 'mytitle'

Comment: i am adding screen shot where i have highlighted with variable i want to create but it is not creating

Comment: @sai Cannot see any screenshots, could you please attach it again?